# Permission denied creating a Maven Enterprise Application on Netbeans on Linux

Tags: linux, maven, netbeans, permission-denied

I am using Netbeans 8.0 and Maven 3.2.2 on Linux Mint 16 and I am trying to create a new Maven Enterprise Project. However, I get the following error when doing it:

**Command:**
cd /path/to/new/project; JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_45/jre M2_HOME=/path/to/apache-maven-3.2.2 /path/to/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=ejb-javaee7 -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=ExampleProject-ejb -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dbasedir=/home/path/to/new/project -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode archetype:generate

**Error:**
Cannot run program "/path/to/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn" (in directory "/path/to/new/project"): error=13, Permission denied

All the paths (of the project, Java home and maven) have the following permissions rwxr-xr-x

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved the problem, I had the /dev/sda2 where I have my /path/to/apache-maven-3.2.2 directory (in my /home directory) without the option "exec" in the file /etc/fstab