# Hudson post build action with Sonar plugin failed

Tags: hudson, hudson-plugins

I try to run a [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) (3.3.3) post build action with the [Sonar plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Sonar+plugin) (2.0.1) in a [free-style project](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch06.html#section-configuring-free-style-project), but I get an error.

**Job log:**

```
[workspace] $ mvn -f /home/hudson/.hudson333/jobs/Test/workspace/pom.xml -e -B sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://sonar/sonar4 ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonar.mycompany.com
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn" (in directory "/home/hudson/.hudson333/jobs/Test/workspace"): error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:187)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:157)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:649)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:266)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:273)
    at hudson.tasks.Maven.perform(Maven.java:267)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.utils.SonarMaven.executeMaven(Son    arMaven.java:149)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.executeSonar(Son    arPublisher.java:331)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarPublisher.perform(SonarPublisher.java:292)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:51)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:736)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:714)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$RunnerImpl.post2(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:652)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1519)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:44)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:82)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:137)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:135)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:130)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1022)
    ... 19 more
Sonar analysis completed: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Maven configuration:**

[image: Maven configuration]

**Hudson files:**

```
.hudson333 [drwxrwxr-x]
    maven [drwxrwxr-x]
        slavebundle [drwxrwxr-x]
            bundled-maven [drwxrwxr-x]
                bin [drwxrwxr-x]
                    mvn [-rwxrwxr-w]
```

**Environment:**

- Cent OS
- Hudson 3.3.3
- Sonar Plugin 2.0.1

I found following links:

- [Bug 430081](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=430081)
- [Bug 417967](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417967)
- [Bug 390373](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=390373)
- [Question 24477450](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477450/permission-denied-creating-a-maven-enterprise-application-on-netbeans-on-linux)

but without a working answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found three different work-arounds:

- Add `mvn` to enviroment `PATH` variable.
- Add an additional Maven version

  1. Maven configuration (see [Hudson Book](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch03.html#section-configure-maven)):

     [image: Maven configuration]
  2. Sonar configuration for the job:

     [image: Sonar configuration]
- Use [legacy Maven project type](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch06.html#section-creating-new-project) with [Legacy Maven 2 job type Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Maven+2+Project+Plugin) (3.0.2)

  1. Maven configuration (see [Hudson Book](http://www.eclipse.org/hudson/the-hudson-book/book-hudson.chunked/ch03.html#section-configure-maven)):

     [image: Maven configuration]

     **Note**: Configuration of Maven is neccessary, because the [Legacy Maven 2 job type Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Maven+2+Project+Plugin) don't know bundled Maven of Hudson.
  2. Sonar configuration for the job:

     [image]